# Difference between iPhone simulator and iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ios-simulator

I'm building a iOS app for iPhone. I'm using a collection view, to display a supplementary view. The collection view is in a view controller with a navigation controller. I've created the supplementary view in as xib, using autolayout and constraints.

I've set the navigation controller to be invisible:

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

When I run the app on my device (iPhone 6) I see this:
[image: screenshot from iPhone 6]

When I run the app on the simulator (iPhone 6) I see this:
[image: screenshot from simulator]

So it seems that the view gets a different layout on the simulator. On the simulator the "*top space to superview*" constraint sees the bottom of the invisible navigation bar as the frame of the superview. Whereas on the actual device, it seen the actual view controller frame as the superview.

**How come the differens? Which one should be trusted?**

Image of top constraint of the supplementary view:
[image]

Comment: To answer your question, I always trust the device over the simulator. That said, there is something weird going on here. I assume you've tried a force clean (Command-shift-option-K)?

Comment: Thank you.. I have, it didn't help..